# A search for closed questions containing a specific string isn't returning any results

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, closed-questions

If I search for ["closed:1 ritchie"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1+ritchie) on Programmers it returns no results even though a search for just ["ritchie"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=ritchie) is returning some closed questions.

[The same search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+ritchie) on Stack Overflow does return the expected results.

I would have said that the search appears to be treating `closed:1` as a search term rather than an option, but the results page seems to indicate that it is being treated as an option:

> 0
>   search results for
>   posts containing
>   ritchie
>   search options
>   closed:1

**NOTE**
It seems to only be this particular search term. A search for ["closed:1 linux"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1+linux) (or indeed any other term) works as expected.

Comment: Well, I think it's more that `closed:1` is only examining the actual *question*, whereas the general search includes content from the answers too (I don't think any of the closed questions have "ritchie" in the actual question). I'm not sure if that's the expected behaviour though.

Comment: @TimStone - ah - so what you are saying is that none of the closed questions contain the text "ritchie" in the **question** itself.

Comment: Yep, exactly. I could see `closed:1 "ritchie"` being applied (correctly or otherwise) as "give me all posts that have a non-null `ClosedDate`, and from that subset look for the text ritchie," which would exclude answers from the running.

Comment: So probably [meta-tag:status-by-design] but confusing nevertheless.

Comment: This should be changed as it's unexpected behavior. If wanted to search only question titles/bodies, I'd use `"search string" closed:1 is:question`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick gander [at this search parameters](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=ritchie+is%3Aquestion) will show you the reason for this. There aren't any results for `closed:1 ritchie` because there aren't any actual closed questions that mention Ritchie. The only questions that mention Ritchie are all open at the moment.

The results you see when searching *just* for `ritchie` are due to *answers* to closed questions. However, the display of the search results isn't entirely strong towards indicating this point.

Comment: It's only expected when you follow the logic.

Comment: I do agree that it's not the clearest of things to expect.